# Why scratches/tape affixed on lenses don't appear in the images captured?

Tags: optics, lenses, camera

I read this article about dirt on lenses. https://photojottings.com/dirty-lens/

In this, the author puts a small tapes on the lens and we can still see the image. We don't see the tape anywhere in the image though, Why? I understand light pass through the lens so we see the scene but why don't we see the tape blobs?

Comment: They are not in the depth of field. It will degrade the general image quality, but will not be anywhere near in-focus.

Comment: If something is *really* out of focus in front of something else that is in focus it won't register as being there since it's all blurry smeared and spread out everywhere in front of something that is much more in focus and clearly there.